# Can't build libcurl

Tags: curl, libcurl

I'm trying to build libcurl with VS2015 on windows but I am having an error that I can't figure out, I've done a lot of searching but can't find anything. Here is the error:

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\curl-7.57.0\winbuild>nmake /f Makefile.vc mode=static VC=14 MACHINE=x64 DEBUG=no

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.00.24210.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

configuration name: libcurl-vc14-x64-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl
Could Not Find C:\Users\user\Desktop\curl-7.57.0\winbuild\LIBCURL_OBJS.inc
Could Not Find C:\Users\user\Desktop\curl-7.57.0\winbuild\CURL_OBJS.inc
        cl /O2 /DNDEBUG /MD /DCURL_STATICLIB /I. /I ../lib /I../include /nologo /W4 /wd4127 /EHsc /DWIN32 /FD /c /DBUILDING_LIBCURL /I"../../deps/include"  /DUSE_WIN32_IDN /DWANT_IDN_PROTOTYPES  /DUSE_IPV6  /DUSE_WINDOWS_SSPI /DUSE_SCHANNEL /Fo"..\builds\libcurl-vc14-x64-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl-obj-lib/file.obj"  ..\lib\file.c
file.c
../include\curl/curl.h(49): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdio.h': No such file or directory
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

What do I do?????

Comment: Do you have Visual C++ installed? If you're missing `stdio.h`, you have much larger problems than building libcurl.

Comment: Yes, i have visual c++ installed.

Answer (score 0):

I re-installed VS2017, used that, and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

Disabling my Antivirus and starting the cmd as an administrator made it work for me.